# Does Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames() return resources from App_LocalResources?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, globalization

I have global and local embedded resources in my project as shown in the image.

[Resources files in my project with **build action as embedded resources**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sQ2b.jpg)

I have a function **ResourceText** as below

```
             public static string GLOBAL_RESOURCES = "SampleClient.App_GlobalResources.Global.resources";

                /// <summary>
                /// Used in JavaScript/front code to return resource translations for current page or global resource file
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="pResourceKey"></param>
                /// <returns></returns>
                /// <remarks></remarks>
                public string ResourceText(string pResourceKey, bool pGlobalResource = false)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pResourceKey)) throw new ArgumentNullException("ResourceKey cannot be empty");

                    if (pGlobalResource)
                    {
                        // Find the value from the global resource

                        ResourceManager tResourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(GLOBAL_RESOURCES.Replace(".resources", ""), this.GetType().BaseType.Assembly);
                        tResourceManager.IgnoreCase = true;

                        string tTranlsation = tResourceManager.GetString(pResourceKey);

                        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(tTranlsation) ? pResourceKey : tTranlsation;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string[] tAssemblyNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
                        try
                        {
                            if (tAssemblyNames.Length >= 1) // There is a local file associated
                            {
                                // Get value from the local resource
                                string tAssemblyName = this.Page.GetType().BaseType.FullName.Insert(this.Page.GetType().BaseType.FullName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1, "App_LocalResources.");


                                string tResName = (from n in tAssemblyNames where n.Contains(tAssemblyName + ".aspx") select n).First().Replace(".resources", "");
                                ResourceManager tResourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(tResName, this.GetType().BaseType.Assembly);

                                tResourceManager.IgnoreCase = true;


                                string tTranlsation = tResourceManager.GetString(pResourceKey);
                                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(tTranlsation) ? pResourceKey : tTranlsation;
                            }
                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw (ex);
                            // Check the local resources
                        }

                    }
                    // Fall back
                    return pResourceKey;
                }
```

Which is called in my aspx page as

```
 <input type="search" id="inputCustomerGroupGridSearch" placeholder="<%= ResourceText("PlaceholderSearch")%>" />
            <button type="button" id="buttonNewCustomerGroup" style="float: right" class="PrimaryButton"><%=ResourceText("ButtonNew")%></button>
```

When I debugged the function ResourceText, the line of code

```
string[] tAssemblyNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

returns only "SampleClient.App_GlobalResources.Global.resources" not "SampleClient.Modules.Customers.App_LocalResources.Customers.resouces". Why is the resources in  App_LocalResources not returned by Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I added strong typed assembly App_LocalResources.resources.dll in my bin folder. Then it was listed in resources names when executing Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();

So, I could call my ResourceText function for both global and local resources.